# Anonymous Users cannot open XLSX/PPTX files from a SharePoint 2010 document library

Tags: 2010, excel, anonymous-authentication

**Scenario :-**

***Environment*** :- SharePoint 2010

we have a Site Collection and sub-site which has complete Anonymous Access and all the Document Libraries under the sub-site are given View Items permission for Anonymous users and it has multiple documents with different file types like (xls, xlsx, ppt, pptx, docx, doc, txt,jpg etc) and we are facing issue in opening files like xlsx/pptx file by anonymous user.

**Issue:-**
Issue is that when ever Anonymous user tries to open xlsx/pptx file , it prompts for Authentication every single time. Please let me know how this can be resolved in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

The cause behind is that Anonymous users do not have "OpenItems" rights on the Document Library. To solve the issue, you need to break the permission on the document library, also make sure that anonymous user has permission to read. The more information can be found here...
https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2498047/anonymous-users-cannot-open-xlsx-files-from-a-sharepoint-document-libr

Answer (score -1):

create an Excel Services Application and start the service on at least one machine in the farm.